# Read all bytes of a file using Julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying to read all the bytes of a file using Julia into an array. So far I have:

```
s = open(file_path,"r")
```

I'm not sure how to tell how big the file is. I'm also not sure that I need to. Perhaps I can just pass an empty array into readbytes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way do do it is to use `read` function.
You can either pass an open stream to it like `data = read(s)` if `s` was opened with the code you have provided above.
Alternatively you can simply write `data = read(file_path)`. In this way you do not have to close the stream yourself.

You can find out the details by reading help of `read` by executing `?read` in Julia REPL.

To get the size of the file in bytes you can use `filesize(file_path)` function.

Comment: The help from the base read function is confusing because it lacks clarification that anything is returned. Perhaps I just need to learn how functions are documented? Read is also a binary function which wasn't obvious initially, which is why I guess there is a readstring function. Regardless, your answer now makes sense although I might clarify it even further with something like `data = read(file_path)`

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of testing this seems to work ...

```
s = open(file_path,"r")
data = UInt8[]
readbytes!(s,data,Inf)
close(s)
```